# MISSING_ARG_APIKEY when post to twitter by Sharekit

Tags: iphone, twitter

how to resolve it?

```
#define SHKTwitterConsumerKey       @""
#define SHKTwitterSecret            @""
#define SHKTwitterCallbackUrl       @"http://example.com/oauth"
#define SHKTwitterUseXAuth          0 
#define SHKTwitterUsername
```

not have anyfield for API key

Answer (score 26):

By default, Sharekit uses bit.ly to shorten URLs when tweeted.  If you don't configure the Bit.ly settings (directly below the Twitter settings) it will fail to shorten the URL and will leave MISSING_ARG_APIKEY in place of the link you're attempting to tweet.  Adding a bit.ly username and API key will solve the problem.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks! I would expect that leaving the Bit.ly settings empty is tantamount to "don't use Bit.ly". It sounds like Bit.ly is mandatory. In my case I'm already using a branded Bit.ly account, and the links I happen to be sharing have already been shortened in advance. A few quick mods and it'll be good to go!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem -- it was actually complaining about not having filled in the login info for the bit.ly url shortener.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to [get an API key from Twitter](http://dev.twitter.com/apps/new). Second, you need to give ShareKit that API key. [The documentation](http://getsharekit.com/install/) suggests that you can configure that in `SHKConfig.h`. That should fix the issue.

Comment: @RAGOpoR: With OAuth, it appears that what was previously an API key is now a combination of the consumer key and a secret, so though the terminology I used might now be incorrect, you still have to register your application and add the relevant details to `SHKConfig.h`.

Comment: i already register and have all key,but shkconfig not have a field to fill my API key